Error when trying to use @import "file" or @use "file"
I use Sass in Angular with WebStorm.
In styles.sass I use:
@import "colors"

In browser, everything works fine, but in the Output tab of Web Storm. I receive this error:
 
cmd.exe /D /C call C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass.cmd styles.sass:C:\Users\user\Desktop\dev\my-app/css/styles.css
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "colors"
  │         ^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  styles.sass 1:9  root stylesheet

Process finished with exit code 65

I have 2 files: colors.sass and colors.css
@import "colors" gives me the error above but @import "colors.css" does not display any errors. Why?
These are my settings in WebStorm:

I get the same error for other files as well. I also tried it with @use "@angular/material". Same error.
This is what I have tried:

Updated Sass and all packages
Deleted node_modules
Restarted WebStorm
Created a new project (I use the latest version of WebStorm)

None of them worked.
Update
I have replaced @import "colors" with @import "styles/colors" and that worked. However, @use "@angular/material" as mat is still not working. I have replaced it with @use "../node_modules/@angular/material" as mat but then I get this error:

> Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.   
> 4 │ @use '@material/typography' as mdc-typography;   
>   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   


Try adding --load-path=<PATH> parameter to the arguments (can be used more than once)

@LazyOne thanks! I have just added --load-path ../node_modules. However, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. To clearify this issue, I have created another quoestion. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78357851/use-works-in-styles-sass-but-not-in-any-compoents

Not an Angular user so cannot advise here (as it can rely on certain tools/loading mechanics that I'm not familiar with). Best idea so far: try absolute paths instead of relative (the IDE allows you to make such a path using different macro)
