@use works in styles.sass but not in any compoents
I am using Sass in Angular with WebStorm.
In custom-theme.scss I have:
@use "@angular/material" as mat;

No error. Everything works fine.
In dialog.component.sass I use
@use "../../../../styles/custom-theme" as customTheme

Then I get this error:

cmd.exe /D /C call C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\sass.cmd --load-path ../node_modules dialog.component.sass:dialog.component.css
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use "@angular/material" as mat;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  ..\..\..\..\styles\custom-theme.scss 1:1  @use
  dialog-error.component.sass 1:1           root stylesheet

Process finished with exit code 65

In styles.sass (root directory) I have:
@use "styles/custom-theme" as theme

No error.
I use Sass and SCSS and both have these arguments:
--load-path ../node_modules $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

How comes that I can use custom-theme.scss in styles.sass but not in any compoents?

Try Import instead of use => @import "../../../../styles/custom-theme" as customTheme

@AlpineA110R I get the same error message.
